# Update Media Metadata from the Receiver

Tags: metadata, google-cast, custom-receiver

I am playing a video on my Custom Receiver via the Media Player Library. In my receiver, I want to update the video Metadata to set the Title of the currently playing media. What is the best way to do this?

Currently, I am updating the Media Information object in the Media Manager when the video starts to play, and this seems to work okay, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? Possibly inside of the Media Manager On Load method I have overridden.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to update the title? That should be set when you load the media.

Comment: The Sender is not setting the title when launching the video, and is instead passing it up in the Custom Data. We would like to take the title from there, and update the Metadata. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Try this: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#setMediaInformation

Comment: any update on this?